# Laravel 8 php artisan queue command not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm learning about queue and jobs on laravel 8, on the documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues) it says to run `php artisan queue:work --queue=high,default` but when I enter the command, my command line just stuck not outputing anything. I have changed the .env `QUEUE_CONNECTION=database` and migrate the queue table but the command still not working.

[CMD Running queue command attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUpbn.png)

Comment: It's not stuck it's listening for queue events. The queue worker is meant to be a service that is permanently running in the background. Try sending something to the queue and see if it says that it's processing it

Comment: In this way queue are waiting for events